# Laravel 5 logout not working properly

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

Though this has been a repeated question, all available solutions have not worked for me.

The issue is that in my app, I am redirecting user to `/auth/logout` to logout.
This in turn logs out a user and redirects to `/auth/login` as it should.
But clicking any navigation links on home page or refreshing the page redirects and logs in the user.

- This is **not a browser caching issue**, because in that case only the page(content) would have been cached. In my case I can use the entire session.(all CRUD operations possible).
- If after logout, I login as another user, the session of the previous user persists i.e. the logged in user is the previous user.
- I have set the `domain` in `session.php` as 'xyz.com` because I am using the same  session across subdomains.
- I have a remember_token() column in users table. The value of this changes on login *and* logout.
- Refreshing on `/auth/login` several times will redirect to `/` with session and sometimes won't. Pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to resolved for now if I redirect to `xyz.com/auth/logout` instead of `sub.xyz.com/auth/logout`.

Strange behaviour. No explanation though.